# How can this inequality be proven?

Tags: calculus

I've been wrestling with this problem for quite a while already and to no avail. Oftentimes when I'm really stuck I look at solution and think to myself "no way would I get to it". I guess this is one of those cases so I decided to ask for help.

$$ \sum _{k=n+1}^{\infty }\:\frac{1}{k!}<\frac{1}{\left(n+1\right)!}\frac{n+1}{n}  $$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: for $k\ge1$ we have $$\frac1{(n+k)!}\le\frac1{(n+1)!}\left(\frac1{n+1}\right)^{k-1}$$

Also the inequality is strict for $k>1$

Comment: It still isn't clear for me how this can be applied to the problem. Could you please explain more or/and link me to something similar ?

Comment: The right hand side is a geometric series! If that does not ring a bell, I will edit the post, let me know.

Comment: Oh boy, I did't even notice that the right hand side is the geometric series. Could you please explain how you can to the inequality you posted ?

Comment: well, from $(n+k)!$ you factor out $(n+1)!$ and you are left with $(n+2)\cdots(n+k)$. In this last product there are $k-1$ factors, each greater than $(n+1)$.